# random shuffle always return None

Tags: python, random, shuffle

i only get None after running random.shuffle in python

```
a = [(6, 7), (6, 5), (7, 4), (4, 4), (9, 8)]
print(f'{a=}')
x = random.shuffle(a)
print(f'{x=}')

>>> a = [(6, 7), (6, 5), (7, 4), (4, 4), (9, 8)]
>>> None
```

Comment: From [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.shuffle). 
"Shuffle the sequence x in place." Therefore you don't need to assign `x` to `random.shuffle(a)`. And can simply shuffle inplace.

Comment: That means ```random.shuffle``` is an inplace function. No nned to assign its value as it will return None of not return anything

Answer (score 1):

From [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.shuffle):

`random.shuffle(x[, random])`

> Shuffle the sequence x in place.

Therefore you don't need to assign `x` to `random.shuffle(a)`. And can simply shuffle inplace.

```py
a = [(6, 7), (6, 5), (7, 4), (4, 4), (9, 8)]
random.shuffle(a)
```